# how to specify existing class as import function return type?

Tags: entity-framework

I use entity framework 5 only for accessing stored procedures, I got my own objects classes
already defined.
when I import a function from the database the return type is something like "SP_Results".
how can I define the return type as a self made existing class?
currently to workaround this problem I do the following:
1) I go to the imported function and choose create new complex type and I give the complex type
   the same name as my existing class and visual studio creates a class with the same name.
2) Then to avoid ambiguity I go and delete the class that visual studio created.
all the functions works great since my existing classes has matching properties to the columns
being retuned from the stored procedures.
another side effect is when I update my model from the database to add more function(stored procedures) visual studio again creates the classes I deleted at another time before.
how do I "work by the book" and avoid this workaround and the side effect?

Thank you all in advance!